# (ffmpeg/menc) how to split movie by given filesize?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mencoder

I am looking for a way to split a larger file into smaller parts - for example a 4GB movie file into 1024MB parts. Does ffmpeg or mencoder this do this job?

I need a filesize specific solution to produce a split by size, and not by time.

Any other app on linux what can do this for me are very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

This tool might be of use: http://mpgtx.sourceforge.net/

From the Examples section:

> I want to split this file at 699 Megs so that it can fit on my Video CD!
>
> mpgtx -s file {699M}
>
> Now processing Chunk 1/2 ...  100.00%
>   Now processing Chunk 2/2 ...  45.31%
>
> Here are chunk-1.mpg and chunk-2.mpg (default basename is chunk)

Not sure if it works with your video format though.